# PM2 deployment permissions denied

Tags: node.js, git, github, ssh, pm2

When I run `pm2 deploy development setup` I get the following error. Which is strange because this key has no password set.

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/spongebob/.ssh/dev.pub':
Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).

  setup paths failed

Deploy failed
```

I have created a key pair with no password, and trasnfered it to my development machine like so:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/virtualbox_dev -o "IdentityFile /Users/spongebob/.ssh/dev" -f dev@192.168.0.17
```

I can log into SSH fine with no password:

```
ssh -o 'IdentityFile /Users/spongebob/.ssh/dev' 'dev@192.168.0.17'
Last login: Sun May 27 12:39:57 2018 from 192.168.0.11
```

I have added this key as a deployment key to Github as this is a private repo (and also added the `virtualbox_dev` key just incase). And tested whether it works ...

```
Hi MyUsername/blue-mask-api! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provideshell access.
```

And here is my deployment configuration (I have this in `package.json`):

```
"deploy": {
    "development": {
      "key": "/Users/spongebob/.ssh/dev.pub",
      "user": "dev",
      "host": "192.168.0.17",
      "ref": "origin/master",
      "path": "/home/dev/",
      "repo": "git@github.com:MyUsername/blue-mask-api.git",
      "post-deploy": "echo 999999999999",
      "ssh_options": [
        "StrictHostKeyChecking=no",
        "PasswordAuthentication=no"
      ]
    }
```

It's confusing because it's asking for a password and there isn't one set. And when I leave it blank I still get permission denied.

Comment: What does your `PasswordAuthentication` value say in  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in your box?

Comment: I have it set to no: `PasswordAuthentication no`

Comment: Is what `PM2` doc says? If not, have your tried flipping it?

Comment: I don't want a password. And PM2 docs suggested turning password off. Which I have done. Do you use pm2 or have any familiarity with it?

Comment: I do use PM2 but not for deployment. I was trying to see if the issue wasn't anything to do with PM2 but just the generic `permission denied` error coz when I had that error I fixed it by switching on the `PasswordAuthentication`

Comment: Ah ok. Yeah it's the first time I've used it for deployment too. I'll file an issue and see what they say.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, I intend to use PM2 for deployment too at some point.

Answer (score 0):

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/spongebob/.ssh/dev.pub':
```

It appears that you're trying to use the wrong key file. The file with the ".pub" extension is the *public* key file. The corresponding file without the ".pub" extension is the *private* key file. When you run an ssh *client* to connect to a remote *server*, you have to provide the private key file to the ssh client. The contents of the public key file are stored on the server (github in this case), where it's used by the ssh server software to confirm that this key can be accepted for authentication.

You ought to have a private key file with the same name as the public file, except without the ".pub" extension:

```
"development": {
  "key": "/Users/spongebob/.ssh/dev",
                                ^^^--note no .pub
```

Comment: It's definitely a public key. Says so in the docs http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/deployment/#using-ssh-keys

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's a public key. And it's not the right file to use, as i explained.

Comment: The docs state to use a public key. Are you saying the docs are incorrect?

Comment: I'm saying that if you're getting the passphrase prompt for the xxx.pub file, then you used the wrong file. That prompt is associated with a client trying to authenticate to a server, and the server needs the private key file at that point, not the public key file. The public key file (with the .pub extension) isn't passphrase-protected in any event.

Comment: You're wrong. I attempted what you suggested though and get exactly the same error. That is not the issue. Do you use PM2 deploy?